# Where can I get full list of giuga numbers discovered so far?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

I want full list of giuga numbers discovered so far , on googling  i found this [list](http://oeis.org/A007850/list). But it is not a complete list?

Where can I get them ? Or is there any non-brute force generating algorithm for those numbers ?

Comment: OEIS is always a useful resource.

Comment: Definitely read the main page for the sequence on OEIS, it gives the definition of Giuga numbers that lends itself to a brute-force generation algorithm. Also, the page mentions that there is another Giuga number not among the first twelve listed.